# Dynamically adding HTML radio button with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, dom, dynamic, input

Being a beginner in jquery, I've got some problems with forms and dynamic elements. I know there's already some topic over here but I've tried a lot of things and nothing is working.
Just a precision : I'm working with Phonegap.

There it is. I've got a form where I have to add radio button from a BDD. i've got the data but can't display it on the page.
Here's my form.

```html
<form action="form.php" method="post" id="catDec"> 
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="field">
        <!-- Here I want my set of radio button -->
    </fieldset>
        <br/>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <select name="selectTest" id="selectTest">
                    <option value="1">Value1</option>
                    <option value="2">Value2</option>
                    <option value="3">Value3</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </div><br/>
       <input type="checkbox" name="cbTest" id="cbTest" class="custom" />
       <label for="cbTest">Some random text</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Continue" data-icon="arrow-r" ><br/>
```

And here is my js function.

```js
tableau[0]="value1";
tableau[1]="value2";
tableau[2]="value3";
tableau[3]="value4";

for (var i=1; i<tableau.length-1; i++) {
    //$("#field").append('<input type="radio" name="rb_catDec" id="'+tableau[i]+'" value="'+tableau[i]+'" checked="checked" />' );
    //$("#field").append('<label for="'+tableau[i]+'">'+tableau[i]+'</label><br/><br/>' );
    //$("#field").html('<input type="radio" name="rb_catDec" id="'+tableau[i]+'" value="'+tableau[i]+'" checked="checked" />' );
    //$("#field").html('<label for="'+tableau[i]+'">'+tableau[i]+'</label><br/><br/>' );
    $("<input type='radio' value='"+tableau[i]+"' />")
        .attr("id", tableau[i])
        .attr("name", "rb_name")
        .prependTo("field");
}
//$("#field").reload();
```

Well, I've tried with the .append and with the .html methods. With a div to place those inputs and without.
I suppose it has something to do with the fact I add these after the loading of the page but I don't find a way to pass over it.

Can someone can help me, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace this code:

```
.prependTo("field");
```

with this:

```
.prependTo("#field");
```

Since, you want to prepend all radio button to the element with the ID `#field` not just the selector `field`.

Reference: [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)

Comment: Thanks ! I've tries so much for just this... But there is another problems.

My radiobuttons appear on the sreen, but they don't take the css from the jquery framework. And, with this method, do you know  how to put a label for the radio button ?

Comment: Add the label dynamically using the `<label>` tag just like you have added the radio button.

Comment: Okay.
And for the css matter ?

I've got somethig like this : 

http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/203/9sai.png

And I sould have something like that : 

http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/5830/cbxj.png

Any idea ?

Comment: May be you need to include the jQuery Mobile for that like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6G3sJ/)... not sure about that css thing!

Comment: I've done it, even if it's not in the code i put here (because it's a looong code and I posted just the interesting part).
The fact is : when I write it manually, I got the right appearance, and when I use my script, it dosen't take the jquery shape. And when I look the page code, It's the exact same thing. It's like it doesn't update after I mamde the process.